# The analogue of magazine "Quant"

Tags: reference-request, contest-math, book-recommendation

As you know there is an amazing math magazine "Quant" which is in Russian language which contains a lot of interesting and challenging contest math problem.

Are there any analogue in English language?

Would be very grateful for any information.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [*Crux Mathematicorum*.](https://cms.math.ca/crux/)

Comment: How to download the latest issues?

Comment: It looks like you need to subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the free Crux Mathematicorum archive at:

https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/

Answer (score 0):

There is an English language version.  You can buy a subscription on Amazon, but it costs $108 for one year - 6 issues.  An old blog gave a mirror site for the English vsn., but it seems to have expired.  There is an online archive site with a pretty complete set of issues, but it's all in Russian.  Perhaps the editions could be translated with Babylon or some such.  I bought a couple of issues a few years back at a bookstore, so there are some paper editions of current issues around.